# How to get the key exchange and authentication protocol in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, network-programming

I am aware of the the method `.getPublicKey()` that returns the Public key type. But, this function does not tell what type of key exchange used (EDH or RSA). If I'm right, it only return the type of the public key. My question is: How can I get the key exchange and authentication protocols used when I initiate SSL connection with a remote server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an `SSLSocket` or an `SSLEngine`, first get the [`SSLSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html), which will give you some information about the current SSL/TLS session.

If you use [`getCipherSuite()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html#getCipherSuite%28%29), you'll get the cipher suite name, which contains the key exchange type (and the encryption algorithm). The cipher suites that are implemented in the Oracle JRE are listed in the [SunJSSE provider documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider). You can find the naming conventions in the [TLS specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#appendix-C): the first part after `TLS_` (or `SSL_` for older names) and before `_WITH_` will tell you the key exchange algorithm (`DHE_DSS`, `DHE_RSA`, `DH_anon`, `DH_DSS`, `DH_RSA`, `NULL` or `RSA`): a relatively simple regular expression should be able to extract the relevant information.

(You're mentioning `getPublicKey()`, but you're not saying where you're calling it. It would have to apply to the server's certificate, also obtained from the `SSLSession`.)

Comment: what about the SSL version ? Can I get it in a way other than calling the `getProtocol()` ?

Comment: @JuryA Why do you need another way to get the same information?

Comment: @JuryA, I don't think there's another way than `getProtocol()`, but it should be sufficient.

Comment: @EJP: No, I don't need another way. But the code I have does not contain `getProtocol()` which is the method that I am aware of. I'm wondering if this piece of information can be extracted by another function ?

Comment: @JuryA What code do you hav that doesn't provide an SSLSession?

Comment: It provides SSLSession but does not get the Protocol which I need.

Comment: @JuryA, you need to get all that from your `SSLSession` instance.

Comment: @JuryA You seem to have done zero research before making your blanket statement that 'the code [you] have doesn't contain getProtocol()'. When you are advised to use, say, the SSLSession class, you are supposed to look it up before coming to these grand decisions.

Comment: Knowing that `getProtocol()` can be used with SSLsession interface to get the version of SSL protocol used in this session. How can I get the supported protocols by the remote host (an not what is being used in the session. i.e, SSLv2, SSLv3 ??)

Comment: @JuryA you can only know the version supported by the server by trying the highest TLS version you can (you can also dismiss SSLv2 altogether, just don't use it). The server will send a [downrev it its Server Hello message](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4346#appendix-E) if it can't support it, and the session will be established with the highest common version (unless the client doesn't want to proceed with a lower version).

Comment: @Bruno: In a Java program that uses `.startHandshake()`. How can I change the client choices to make it the highest or lowest version ? What is the default thing that happens in case if I didn't specify anything from the client ?

Comment: Look into `SSLSocket.setEnabledProtocols`, check the [*Protocols* section here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) too. In practice, you may just have to try multiple connections "*Some servers do not implement forward compatibility correctly and refuse to talk to TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 clients. For interoperability, SunJSSE does not enable TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 by default for client connections.*".

Comment: @Brunu: I tried to run a program with .getProtocol. Some remote hosts returned NONE. what does this means please. Java page does not give useful information about this. all what they said is that it returns String.

Comment: @JuryA You can't get the SSL protocols supported by the remote host. You can only get the actual protocol that was negotiated, which depends on the enabled protocols at both ends. That is the purpose of the SSL protocol-negotiating handshake.

Comment: Modern TLSv1.3 doesn't include the key exchange or authentication type in the cipher suite, so unfortunately this technique won't work with TLSv1.3.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that `.getPublicKey()` is the method of [Certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html)
You can either use [PublicKey#getAlgorithm()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getAlgorithm%28%29) to find the algorithm

> String getAlgorithm()
>
> Returns the standard algorithm name for this key. For example, "DSA"
>   would indicate that this key is a DSA key. See Appendix A in the Java
>   Cryptography Architecture API Specification & Reference for
>   information about standard algorithm names.

Comment: That's for the cert's public key algorithm, not for the type of key exchange, as asked in the question.